# Envío automático de sms (Python, Windows)

Tags: python, api, sms

Estoy en unas prácticas en empresa y me han propuesto un proyecto.

Trata de hacer un script en Python para Windows que mande sms de manera automática a los clientes para recordarles una cita anual (coger de la base de datos la fecha de la última visita y cuando haya pasado 1 año, mandar sms).

He visto que hay varios servicios de sms, pero me gustaría saber si podéis recomendarme alguno por aquí que tenga buena documentación de su API, o un poco de guía sobre cómo proceder, ya que nunca he hecho nada parecido y el "jefe" tiene aún menos idea que yo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es utilizar una Api puedes utilizar la de https://www.twilio.com/ esta bien documentada . 
Este seria un ejemplo:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' #tu sid de tu cuenta
auth_token = 'your_auth_token' # tu token
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages.create(body='HolaMundo!',from_='+15017122661',to='+15558675310')
print(message.sid)
```